# Whats wrong with this MYSQL INSERT syntax?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, insert

INSERT INTO `all_contributions` (`ID`, `dateofpayment`, `Incometype`, `Serialnumber`, `Contacttype`, `Firstname`, `Autoid`, `Destinationcode`, `Destinationcode2`, `Admitname`, `paymentamount`, `taxclaimable`, `is_processed`,`Paymenttype`) VALUES (NULL, 01/09/2013, DONATION, 000xxxx, Individual, Andy, PLG0003671402, WEB, 473501, B21094, 16.67, No, 0, Direct Debit);

Invalid insert query #1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Debit)' at line 5

This is from a PHP script, with the values shown coming from a file to an array called $parts. The value of Paymenttype is 'DIRECT DEBIT' and the PHP variable used is $parts[4].  It appears that having 2 words in the field causes the problem? All the table fields except is_processed are varchar (and Paymenttype is varchar(20)), but the error says syntax and I can't see what's wrong.  I'm a MYSQL beginner, btw. I have wrestled this for quite a while and have tried moving fields around but it hasn't helped! The field names have left ticks around them, btw.
I'm using MYSQL 5.5.45-cll

Comment: Strings must be enclosed in single quotes `'abc'` or in double quotes `"abc"` in `VALUES`

Comment: Thanks - that's very helpful.  I have a lot to learn.